# How does assembly ORG instruction calculate offset?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, memory-segmentation

I am trying to create a simple BIOS boot sector, for which I use an x86 assembly language. I found out that the layout of memory throughout the booting process looks like the picture beneath this text. My idea is to use the *ORG* assembly instruction to inform the assembler to set a relative memory address *(in this case 0x7c00)*. This way I do not have to bother about calculating memory addresses on the spot. The assembly code looks like this:

```
[org 0x7C00]
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, [0x09]    ;this is the offset of 'the_secret'
    int 0x10

the_secret:
    db "X"

    times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55
```

The problem is that when I assemble this code into binary and start the boot process, the "X" does not come up in the terminal. What is the mistake I am making here?

[image]

Comment: The assembler didn't compute an offset you specified it as [0x09] (fixed memory address). When writing a boot loade if you use ORG 0x7c00 you will want to ensure DS is set to zero before accessing memory. In your case DS likely had 0 in it and you referenced memory at 0x0000:0x0009 when I think you were attempting to read 0x0000:0x7c09. If you had used `mov al, [the_secret]` then the assembler would have computed an offset as 0x7c09.

Comment: you need to put an infinite loop or something after the `int 10h` so execution does not proceed into whatever random memory contents found beyond.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you for clarification. Just out of curiosity: Is it possible to manually change a Data Segment, which I assume is a register that stores the current index of a data segment?

Comment: @DamianKowalski Can you explain what you mean by “change a data segment?”  In real mode, segment registers simply hold the start addresses of segments, shifted to the right by four bits.  You can load them with other values to change into a different segment.

Comment: You can change the Data Segment DS at runtime with something like `mov ax, 0` `mov ds, ax`. When you reference a memory address with [] it is relative to the DS segment (as long as you don't use the BP register in the memory reference). so it is like writing DS:[] or in your case DS:[0x09]. At run time (when the bootloader is running) the value in a segment is used to compute physical memory address. The value in a segment is multiplied by 0x10 and the offset is added to it.

Comment: Had you loaded DS with 0x07c0 (`mov ax, 0x07c0` `mov ds, ax`) and tried to reference address [0x09] (DS:[0x09] the calculation at runtime would have been 0x07c0 * 0x10 (16 decimal) + 0x09 which would have been 0x7c09 and your code would have worked. Note if you set the segment at runtime with 0x07c0 you need to set the ORG to 0x0000. Of course if you add more code the offset 0x09 would change accordingly. But no reason to use fixed offsets, use the label name like `the_secret` and let the assembler compute the offset.

Comment: A good resource on segment:offset memory addressing in real mode on the x86 can be found in [Starmans](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html) tutorial. The tutorial actually uses bootloaders for the examples.

Comment: Thank you so much, that answers my question! The second part was purely theoretical, but that helped me gain more understanding towards how memory is handled.

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned that the offset of the 'X' is 7, not 9.

Comment: I used a command nasm -f bin boot.asm -i boot.bin to assemble it, looked up the binary using bless boot.bin and counted the offset, it was 9, however maybe I am misunderstanding something

EDIT: It was offset 9, because I forgot to include the jmp $ instruction in the aforementioned code, that I have locally

Answer (score 0):

It's best to let the assembler calculate the offset for you.

```
[org 0x7C00]
    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax


    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, [the_secret]  ;load the ascii code for 'X' into AL
    int 0x10

    JMP $    ;halt

the_secret:
    db "X"
    
    times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: If you have `org 7C00h` you want `ds` equal to zero, not 7C0h and most certainly not 7C00h. You clearly didn't test this. Also, an explicit `ds:` segment override is unneeded in NASM assembly and will make the assembler emit a useless prefix. (Except if your address contains `bp`, `esp`, or `ebp` as a base.)

Comment: Fair enough, this is why I just use `mov ax,@code`/`mov ds,ax`. I was under the impression that `the_secret` was relative to `0x7C00`.

Comment: The whole point of ORG is to tell the assembler what to assume when calculating the offset for you.  That's why it's always necessary to set `ds` before using an offset, if you're trying to reach a fixed *linear* address (like `0x7C00 + (the_secret - $)` in this case).  The code in the question is not safe/portable, some BIOSes will start an MBR bootloader with DS=0, some with DS=07C0.